# Get the name of an annotated field

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

If I had defined an annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Input {

    String type() default "text";
    String name();
    String pattern() default "";

}
```

and use it for this methods:

```
@Column(name="nome", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Order(value=1)
@Input
private String nome;

@Column(name="resumo", length=140)
@Order(value=2)
@Input
private String resumo;
```

Is there any way to assign to attribute `name` the name of the annotated field (for instance: for the field `String nome` the value would be `nome` and for the field `String resumo` would be `resumo`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot default the annotation variables to field names. But where ever you are processing the annotation, you can code such that it defaults to field's name. Example below

```
Field field = ... // get fields
Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(Input.class);

if(annotation instanceof Input){
    Input inputAnnotation = (Input) annotation;
    String name = inputAnnotation.name();
    if(name == null) { // if the name not defined, default it to field name
        name = field.getName();
    }
    System.out.println("name: " + name); //use the name
}
```